# Donation totals

Tags: custom-field

I am the only admin in a small nonprofit that uses SF for tracking donors and donations. Though I set up our agency about 15 years ago, we use SF only for the most basic reports and tracking (as I am an accidental admin). Round about mid-2021 I think the onset of Lightning Force (which I only barely grok) caused a very handy plug-in to detonate. I formerly was able to see by year a total of donations on Contact records (and Past Donation Total). Now that is inoperable. Any hamhanded attempt by me to generate something that might fill in this blank has not worked.

I tried roll up fields, but the setup process does not allow me access to the Opportunity/Donation related list and I can't figure out how to make it accessible. Opportunities are listed as a related field on the Contact record.

I know this question is way more basic than most of what posts here -- but again -- I am a (smart but) accidental admin and know only the most basic of maneuvers. I've poked around board and google and can't find this particular item covered. Everything seems to send me to NPSP which I think costs $$ and I don't believe we have.

Any tips around this are appreciated... I'm lost right now. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Actually the Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP) is free.  The best resource for learning about NPSP and getting help from the community is this Trailblazer group.  Be sure to check the right sidebar for intro material.  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kHitSAE?tab=discussion

Also check the Salesforce / Dreamforce channels on youtube for nonprofit-related presentations.

Comment: One consideration when looking into NPSP is that it is a huge package which means your org will be somewhat polluted. Also, it will require you to spend quite some time on understanding it to get the value out of it. 
If it's just the summation you're trying to accomplish, I'd suggest looking into DLRS (declarative lookup roll-up summaries) which is explained quite well here: https://www.salesforceben.com/guide-to-salesforce-dlrs-declarative-lookup-roll-up-summaries/

Comment: Thank you both! I work part-time and won't get a chance to check this out until Monday but I'm so very thankful for the leads! Gracias!

Comment: @GuyClairbois -- I think the DLRS is just what I was looking for! It will take a bit of reading for me to come up to speed, but I did a test that seemed promising! :-) Thank you so much! High Five.

Comment: @DavidCheng Thank you for the hints about trailhead, etc. I hope to spend more time there as I'm able. I appreciate the direction (and to read 'How to Ask' -- I think my newbie-ness showed!) :-)